# How to change `src` value of an HTML using Flask and MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, flask

So I am trying to make some kind of an album website. There are 2 databases. One for users and selected_place and one for albums, which includes IMGs. The user will choose where to put the image. I am having a hard time changing the `src` value of the selected_place.

To sum up, the user will choose a place and then the selected place will change its `src` value. The picture must stay on the HTML page. From what I tried it goes away after I logout.

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<tbody>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><td class="picture1"><a href="1" target="_blank"><span class="picture-number">1</span></a><br/><img id="1-img" width="25" height="25" src="1" class="placeholder-img"></td></td>
      <td><td class="picture2"><a href="2" target="_blank"><span class="picture-number">2</span></a><br/><img id="2-img" width="25" height="25" src="2" class="placeholder-img"></td></td>
      <td><td class="picture3"><a href="3" target="_blank"><span class="picture-number">3</span></a><br/><img id="3-img" width="25" height="25" src="3" class="placeholder-img"></td></td>
      <td><td class="picture4"><a href="4" target="_blank"><span class="picture-number">4</span></a><br/><img id="4-img" width="25" height="25" src="4" class="placeholder-img"></td></td>
      <td><td class="picture5"><a href="5" target="_blank"><span class="picture-number">5</span></a><br/><img id="5-img" width="25" height="25" src="5" class="placeholder-img"></td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="static/grid_homepage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
def get_selected_picture_image(user_id):
    user_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=user_database
    )
    user_cursor = user_connection.cursor()
    user_cursor.execute("SELECT selected_picture FROM users WHERE id = %s", (user_id,))
    selected_picture = user_cursor.fetchone()

    if selected_picture:
        picture_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=database
        )
        picture_cursor = picture_connection.cursor()
        picture_cursor.execute("SELECT Img FROM pictures WHERE Picture_ID = %s", (selected_picture[0],))
        picture_image = picture_cursor.fetchone()
        if picture_image:
            image_data = picture_image[0]
            encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')
            picture_cursor.close()
            picture_connection.close()
        else:
            encoded_image = None
            print("Picture resmi bulunamadı.")

    user_cursor.close()
    user_connection.close()

    return encoded_image if selected_picture else None
```

So I tried, making a dictionary and then give the HTML elements {{selected_picture['0']}},but the thing is that when the user logout the pictures disappear from the HTMl. I tried dictionary. It works, but only for the user. I also tried,

```
def update_html_src(user_id):
    user_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=user_database
    )
    user_cursor = user_connection.cursor()
    user_cursor.execute("SELECT selected_picture FROM users WHERE id = %s", (user_id,))
    selected_picture = user_cursor.fetchone()

    if selected_picture:
        picture_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=database
        )
        picture_cursor = picture_connection.cursor()
        picture_cursor.execute("SELECT Img FROM pictures WHERE Picture_ID = %s", (selected_picture[0],))
        picture_image = picture_cursor.fetchone()
        if picture_image:
            image_data = picture_image[0]
            encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')
            picture_cursor.close()
            picture_connection.close()
            
            # HTML dosyasını güncelle
            with open("grid_homepage.html", "r") as file:
                html_content = file.read()
            
            updated_html_content = html_content.replace(f'src="{selected_picture[0]}"', f'src="{encoded_image}"')
            
            with open("grid_homepage.html", "w") as file:
                file.write(updated_html_content)
                
        else:
            encoded_image = None
            print("Picture resmi bulunamadı.")

    user_cursor.close()
    user_connection.close()

    return encoded_image if selected_picture else None
```

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var selectedPictureImage = "{{ selected_picture_image }}"; // Seçili pikselin resim URL'sini al
    
      // Her bir pikselin src değerini değiştir
      var pictureImages = document.querySelectorAll(".placeholder-img");
      for (var i = 0; i < pictureImages.length; i++) {
        pictureImages[i].src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + selectedPictureImage;
      }
    });
    If I use this still everything becomes the same.